# Calculate Errors using loop function in R

Tags: r, matrix

I have two data matrices both having the same dimensions. I want to extract the same series of columns vectors. Then take both series as vectors, then calculate different errors for example mean absolute error **(mae)**, mean percentage error **(mape)** and root means square error
**(rmse)**. My  data matrix is quite large dimensional so I try to explain with an example and calculate these errors  manually as:

```
mat1<- matrix(6:75,ncol=10,byrow=T) 
mat2<- matrix(30:99,ncol=10,byrow=T) 
mat1_seri1 <- as.vector(mat1[,c(1+(0:4)*2)])
mat1_seri2<- as.vector(mat1[,c(2+(0:4)*2)])
mat2_seri1 <- as.vector(mat1[,c(1+(0:4)*2)])
mat2_seri2<- as.vector(mat1[,c(2+(0:4)*2)])
mae1<-mean(abs(mat1_seri1-mat2_seri1))
mae2<-mean(abs(mat1_seri2-mat2_seri2))
For mape 
mape1<- mean(abs(mat1_seri1-mat2_seri1)/mat1_seri1)*100
mape2<- mean(abs(mat1_seri2-mat2_seri2)/mat1_seri2)*100
```

similarly, I calculate **rmse** from their formula, as I have large data matrices so manually it is quite time-consuming. Is it's possible to do this using looping which gives an output of the errors **(mae,mape,rmse)** term for each series separately.

Comment: In what way would you like to automate the process? you can turn it into a function as well.

Comment: thanks for your reply and time, yes I want to do this automatically, as I am new to r is it possible through function.

Comment: please help me that how i colud this through function/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but here is a function that could automate the process, maybe there is also a better way:

```
fn <- function(m1, m2) {
  stopifnot(dim(m1) == dim(m2))
  
  mat1_seri1 <- as.vector(m1[, (1:ncol(m1))[(1:ncol(m1))%%2 != 0]])
  mat1_seri2 <- as.vector(m1[, (1:ncol(m1))[!(1:ncol(m1))%%2]])
  mat2_seri1 <- as.vector(m2[, (1:ncol(m2))[(1:ncol(m2))%%2 != 0]])
  mat2_seri2 <- as.vector(m2[, (1:ncol(m2))[!(1:ncol(m2))%%2]])
  
  mae1 <- mean(abs(mat1_seri1-mat2_seri1))
  mae2 <- mean(abs(mat1_seri2-mat2_seri2))
  
  mape1 <- mean(abs(mat1_seri1-mat2_seri1)/mat1_seri1)*100
  mape2 <- mean(abs(mat1_seri2-mat2_seri2)/mat1_seri2)*100
  
  setNames(as.data.frame(matrix(c(mae1, mae2, mape1, mape2), ncol = 4)), 
           c("mae1", "mae2", "mape1", "mape2"))
}

fn(mat1, mat2)

  mae1 mae2    mape1    mape2
1   24   24 92.62581 86.89572
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and interest in solving the problem, I am thankful to you, when I run your code I got the following errors ``` Error: unexpected '>' in:

  as.data.frame(matrix(c(mae1, mae2, mape1, mape2), ncol = 4)) |> ``` and another error ``` Error in setNames(c("mae1", "mae2", "mape1", "mape2")) : 
  argument "nm" is missing, with no default ``` please rectify if possible

Comment: you're welcome, can you try it now. `|>` is new native R pipe operator to replace its `LHS` to the first argument of its `RHS`. But it raises that Error in Rstudio as is the case for mine, but it does not bring the function execution to a halt. You may try the edited version.

Comment: You're welcome. I will try to improve it further, but is it always 2 matrices of the same dimension involved? If that's the case I will see how it can be less hard-coded.

Comment: can we do this by looping, as in my data I have more than two series in one case I have seven series, and in another case I have twenty-four series, So basically I want that through looping each pair of series is selected through loop one by one and calculate mean square error and mean percentage error for each selected pair.

Comment: I've been meaning to do so, so if I understood you completely you would like to calculate these two parameters for every combination of 7 series and 24 series, taking one matrix from each series and the other from another series? It's quite possible no problem, I just want to have a clear idea of the problem at hand.

Comment: thanks for your time, as I have two data matrices of the same dimensions 24 rows (hours) and 365 columns (days). One matrix is forecasted and the other is observed. I want to check the accuracy of my model according to days of the week and second-way hourly basis, so for daily accuracy, I take all for example Sundays from both the matrices(which defined by the series for each day), and take it as vector and calculate the mae and mape. so I want that through loops it select the same series from the two matrices and calculte the mae and mape for each day automatically.

Comment: In a second way for hourly accuracy of the model. In the data matrices the first row is the first hour, so I have 24 rows, know I want to measure the accuracy on an hourly basis, for example, for the first hour, the first row is selected from both the matrices, calculate the accuracy through errors, similarly for other hours. I want through loop select the corresponding row from both matrices for each hour and calculate accuracy errors separately for each hour.

Comment: Maybe it would be better if you could ask a new question, but this time share a sample of your data that best represents the above situation as I think it is very different to the situation we had in the current question. So in that way we may have a clearer idea of your data structure.